# Counting combinations of all possible cases

Tags: combinatorics

An academic department offers 6 lower level courses $\{L_1, L_2, L_3, L_4, L_5, L_6\}$ and 8 higher level courses: $\{H_1, H_2, H_3, H_4, H_5, H_6, H_7, H_8\}$. A valid curriculum consists of 4 lower and 5 higher level courses.

Suppose that $\{H_1, H_2, H_3\}$ have $L_1$ as a prerequisite, and $\{H_3, H_4, H_5\}$ have $L_2$ and $L_3$ as prerequisites. i.e any curricula which involve, say, one of $\{H_1, H_2, H_3\}$ must also include $L_1$. How many different curricula are there?

I want to know if following approach is correct:

We need to consider several cases:

1. If $L_1$ is not chosen, then there are $C(3, 2)$ combinations to choose lower level courses (as $L_2$ and $L_3$ should definitely be chosen, otherwise, we wont be able to choose any of higher courses and there will be left three choices $(L_4, L_5, L_6)$ and we need to choose 2 of them) any of higher courses.
2. If $L_1$ is chosen and neither $L_2$ nor $L_3$ is chosen. There are $C(3, 3)$ combinations which equals to 1 and we also need to choose all courses of higher level which are not blocked by prerequisites as only 5 of them are left.
3. If $L_1$ is chosen and $L_2$ or $L_3$. So it means that we can choose $C(3, 2)$ combinations from lower level courses and here again all higher level courses should be chosen. But in this case answer should be multiplied by 2, as there are two cases, when $L_2$ is chosen first and $L_3$ is chosen second.
4. If $L_1, L_2, L_3$ are all chosen. We only need one lower level course and there is $C(3, 1)$ choices and all higher level courses are allowed now so $C(8, 5)$. The answer here will be $C(3,1) \cdot C(8,5)$.

Comment: if you didn't have restrictions you'd have C(6,4)*C(8,5) = 840 choices.

Comment: No, we have restrictions. We can't choose H1, H2, H3, if we haven't chosen L1 and H3, H4, H5, if we haven't chosen both L2 and L3.

Comment: I know we do I was just giving you the upper bound.

Comment: It looks right to me.